# Maven pom file, what is it doing?

Tags: java, maven

I have just started using Maven, in a newbie capacity, just want to understand something around dependencies. 
I am trying to build a micro web service using iText and the pdf output functionality.
So my very first steps is seeing if I can get a pdf output from a very simple Java program.

In my pom file i have the following dependencies:

```
<!-- iText Core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>${itext.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<!-- iText pdfHTML add-on -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

After reading the information on the Maven site, the pom file should do all of the heavy lifting in getting the dependencies, this is the bit i'm a little confused on. 
Will the pom file physically download the files to the the app location on application start so that he app can utilize these files?

if that's the case it doesn't seem to be doing this and so am I missing something in the pom file to enable this?

The full pom file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <itext.version>RELEASE</itext.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- iText Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- iText pdfHTML add-on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
      </dependency>   
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be doing this" is very vague. What exactly did you do and what error did you get?

Comment: The POM doesn't _do_ anything; it's a description ("model"). The Maven Reactor does the things, usually with `mvn` from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When maven build is executed, Maven automatically downloads all the dependency jars into the local repository.

the local repository of Maven is a folder location on the developer's machine, where all the project artifacts are stored locally.

Usually this folder is named **.m2**.

Here's where the default path to this folder is – based on OS:

**Windows**: C:\Users\User_Name\ .m2

**Linux**: /home/User_Name/.m2

**Mac**: /Users/user_name/.m2

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository

Comment: Thanks Daniel, So when i run the package command in Maven for the project, will the dependency files be wrapped up into the jar file?

Comment: @JeepersCreepers when you run mvn install a jar will be stored in the local repository for each version of the project

Answer (score 0):

Maven does download the dependencies to the local m2 repository. But this is more meant for building the application, not for running.

What you want (copy the dependencies next to the output jar) can be achieved with the goal dependency:copy-dependencies

See this blog post:

https://technology.amis.nl/2017/02/09/download-all-directly-and-indirectly-required-jar-files-using-maven-install-dependencycopy-dependencies/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really helpful for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Managing dependencies is one of the key features of Maven.

> Dependency management: It is possible to define dependencies to other
>   projects. During the build, the Maven build system resolves the
>   dependencies and it also builds the dependent projects if needed.

Resolving dependencies does mean it downloads all the specified jars in the local system.

> The Maven tooling reads the pom file and resolves the dependencies of
>   the project. Maven validates if required components are available in a
>   local repository. The local repository is found in the .m2/repository
>   folder of the users home directory.

Note that .m2/ is a hidden folder. If you are using Linux, would be this path /home/someuser/.m2

[Read this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheMaven/article.html#maven_overview)

If however its not downloading the jars or creating the .m2 directory at all, then either you are not building the project right or you are not connected to the internet.